# troubleshooting network windows

Tags: windows-xp, troubleshooting

Working on an older network not built by me (seems to have been set up about 8-10 years ago). It happens to be a POS system where one machine functions not only as a POS machine (Will call SERVER), but also as a server for 3 other POS machines (Will call POS1-POS3)...

Recently (within the last 2 months) the SERVER has begun to just randomly drop its network connection. (Initially, my thought was not that it was the machine itself, but rather different parts of the network as when the SERVER dropped, it takes the other machines with it). Anyway, we have replaced the Cable Modem (initial issues began with loss of internet), then replaced the router, and finally bypassed the onboard NIC card of the SERVER with a USB to ethernet adapter. No replacement has led to the machine operating correctly. We discovered today that if we try to send a large file from the SERVER to another machine across the network, it will result in the SERVER losing network connectivity. That being said:

- All machines are/were Windows XP POS Embedded POSIFLEX touchscreen machines. -Old Router was a WRT54GL, replaced with a new (Walmart Special) Belkin A/C router (i forget model off the top of my head).
- Cable Modem was an older Docsis 2.0 Motorola, replaced with the updated docsis 3.0 version (i can post models... but it seems to be functioning fine) -system runs on 192.168.1.X (It has occurred to me that there may be a rogue item on the network screwing with this structure and I will change tomorrow to 192.168.7.X or something)
- old SERVER has been replaced today with a new machine that acts as a dedicated server and no issues have occurred with it or the rest of the network since..
- disconnecting the cat5 cable from the SERVER and immediately reconnecting it after network loss will bring the connectivity back.
- I have not replaced the cat5 cable itself yet as doing so is a little invasive (i have also not tested the line yet as it had not occurred to me that that might be the underlying issue until this evening)...
- All machines use a static IP address.

All of that being said, what tests could/should I run to rule out causes, what are the logical things that could cause this issue?

Comment: When the server was having issues, how much free memory did it have left?

Comment: Please provide specifics.  I can't do any research with "i don't have the model number" and "I can post the model".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure... but i will check tomorrow. (But I do know that it had 2GB total). We've been able to replicate the loss off connectivity by copying large files across the network (from it to other machines)).

Comment: Machine has 2GB total, 1GB free when the copy begins and it remains pretty consistent when the drop happens (no major dip in free memory... as in doesn't move from the 1GB range) Additionally, system cache, kernel memory stay about the same. CPU usage goes from ~0 to ~8%